# Is this LINQ dynamic orderby method thread safe?

Tags: c#, linq

After searching online and going through past stackoverflow posts for a suitable implementation for dynamic ordering with linq, i came up with my own implementation that [borrows a few things](http://www.singingeels.com/Blogs/Nullable/2008/03/26/Dynamic_LINQ_OrderBy_using_String_Names.aspx) from other solutions i have previously seen.

What i need to know is if this implementation is threadsafe? I don't believe it is as i am passing an enumerable generic type object (reference type) as a parameter into the static method but i would like to know if i am missing anything else and hopefully how to make it completely threadsafe.

```
public class OrderByHelper
{

    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(IQueryable<T> items, string sortColumn, string sortDirection, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T).GetProperty(sortColumn).PropertyType;
        return (IEnumerable<T>)(typeof(OrderByHelper)
                        .GetMethod("OrderByKnownType")
                        .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(T), t })
                        .Invoke(null, new object[] { items, sortColumn, sortDirection, pageNumber, pageSize }));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<K> OrderByKnownType<K, T>(IQueryable<K> items, string sortColumn, string sortDirection, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(K), "i");
        var mySortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<K, T>>(Expression.Property(param, sortColumn), param);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortDirection))
        {
            if (sortDirection == "ASC")
                return items.OrderBy(mySortExpression).Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            else
                return items.OrderByDescending(mySortExpression).Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No sorting direction specified.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple:

It is thread safe if your original collection is thread safe.

All extension methods in LINQ merely call `.GetEnumerator()` of the original collection. Sorting and Ordering doesn't manipulate the original collection, but rather lets you enumerate it in a sorted order. Thus, you only do read operations on the data. As a general rule of thumb, if you only do read data, you do not need to implement any thread safety.

I'm tempted to say that in 99% of cases you don't need any thread safety, because you collect data only once and then expose the LINQ functionality. You might only need a thread safe collection if you want to create a framework that does not instantiate new collections when refreshing data, but rather keeps re-using the same (observable) collection instance that synchronizes itself with the database data in a fancy way.

But I don't know about your exact scenario. If you *really* do need thread safety, then it depends if you have control over the code where the original collection is instantiated and the data is added.

If you are using merely LINQ-to-objects, then it's entirely in your control to create an instance of a thread safe collection class at that spot.

If you're using LINQ-to-SQL or anything, then it might be difficult because the original collection that collects the data from the database is probably instantiated deep within the provider and hidden from you. I haven't looked at it though if there are extension points where you can override stuff to use a thread safe collection instead.